# IIS rewrite always triggers the same rule

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have a issue with configuring IIS to do URL rewrite.

I have an aplication running on tomcat using port 1512 and IIS runing on port 80 where i want to catch two different cases:

1) calls coming in on port 80 without any add-on, myserver:80/, should be routed to myserver:1512/pim/webaccess

2) calls coming in with pim in the url, myserver:80/pim/scripts/script.js, should be routed to myserver:1512/pim/scripts/script.js

I have setup two rules like below but when running this it always fire the one in example 1 above which results in the login page being returned instead of e.g. the js file. Not sure what I am doing wrong?

The links to e.g. script files are on the format /pim/scripts/script.js in the login page can that have something to do with it?

Getting really frustrated right now :P

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="false" destination="http://myserver123:1512/pim/webaccess" exactDestination="true" />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="UrlWithPimRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="/pim.*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
                    </serverVariables>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:1512{R0}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="UrlWithoutPIM" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="/*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
                    </serverVariables>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:1512/pim/webaccess" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="RestoreAcceptEncoding" preCondition="NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding">
                    <match serverVariable="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" pattern="^(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding">
                        <add input="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" pattern=".+" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
        <urlCompression doStaticCompression="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules What does FRT say?

Answer (score 0):

I found you used the `/pim.` as the url match part. But it will just match the  `pim/scripts/script.js` url pattern. So you will find it just always doesn't match the first rule.

The right rule is as below:

```
             <rule name="UrlWithPimRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="pim.*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                <serverVariables>
                    <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                    <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
                </serverVariables>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:1512{R0}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
            </rule>
```

Comment: that just gives me a 403 - forbidden response sadly. Any ideas on why?

Comment: Could you please tell me which url you have used faced the 403 error?

Comment: see my new comment.

Answer (score 0):

@brando-zhang

I changed the original rules and now I have the below config. The initial one just going to http://servername:123/ works but everything else like e.g. http://servername:123/pim/scripts/script.js gives me a 404 for some reason. Any ideas??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="false" />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="UrlWithPimRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="pim.*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" />
                    </conditions>
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
                    </serverVariables>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://localhost:1512/{R0}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="UrlWithoutPIM" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="/pim" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" />
                    </conditions>
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
                    </serverVariables>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://localhost:1512/pim/webaccess" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="RestoreAcceptEncoding" preCondition="NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding">
                    <match serverVariable="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" pattern="^(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding">
                        <add input="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" pattern=".+" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
        <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" />
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```